# How to do rest authentication with Spring Social?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-social, spring-security-oauth2

I have implemented Spring Social + Spring Security as outlined in the Spring security examples (and with spring security java config). I reported couple of problems at the time (see https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2204) all of those are resolved and my security works fine.

However, I want to change my security implementation and use RESTful authentication. Spring oauth/oauth2 (http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/) solves this problem but I can not see how Spring Social will fit into that picture? Although behind the scenes Spring social talks to Facebook/Twitter with oauth, I don't think Spring Social's signup form and other characteristics are built for a restful API.

Any examples or ideas will definitely help.

**Update on this post: (4/6/2014)**

- I have built a (PHP) site that consumes my API.
- This PHP site (let's call it the client site), uses Facebook PHP SDK to register its own users. This is a completely separate way of gathering its own members.
- However, once users are registered client site passes username, email, password, first name, and last name data along with its client_id and client secret and using OAuth2 grant type `client_credentials` authentication.
- This passed-in user data creates a user record on the main system! (main application)
- After this, each time the client site calls the main system via OAuth2 grant type password and sends `client_id`, `client_secret`, username and password, gets an "Authentication token" and be able to communicate with the main site with this token.

Seems like a long way to go but solves the problem of keeping the user record on the main system. I'm curious if there are other ways to do this? Please advise.

Comment: Have you looked at this example? https://github.com/joshlong/the-spring-rest-stack

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33963286/2050333

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Social Authentication Filter for Stateless REST Endpoints which use Facebook Token for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911723/spring-social-authentication-filter-for-stateless-rest-endpoints-which-use-faceb)

Comment: https://geowarin.github.io/social-login-with-spring.html-- This could help you very much

Answer (score 2):

So you want to use Oauth2 in your application, and you want to use the password flow.
You can use the spring security oauth2-resource-server project to implement a resource server.
In your resource server you can use the ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails to provide the client_id, client_secret, username and password,
The Oauth2RestTemplate can be used to call the resource server.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring-social was deprecated in 2019](https://spring.io/blog/2018/07/03/spring-social-end-of-life-announcement). In the case that was exposed in the question (long before this deprecation), the easiest sollution is using an authorization-server capable of federating "social" identities out of the box. Keycloak is a free "on premise" sample and Auth0 a SaaS one (with free tier). Just search for "OIDC authorization-server" in your favorite search engine and pick the one best matching your needs.

REST APIs are then configured as resource-servers using `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`. Samples [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials).

Answer (score 0):

Wow, lots of good information already provided by others but Spring Docs provides sample config yaml file to authenticate with Google and Okta, see link below (apologies if already provided).

```
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/reactive/oauth2/login/core.html#webflux-oauth2-login-common-oauth2-provider
Configuring Custom Provider Properties
There are some OAuth 2.0 Providers that support multi-tenancy, which results in different protocol endpoints for each tenant (or sub-domain).

For example, an OAuth Client registered with Okta is assigned to a specific sub-domain and have their own protocol endpoints.

For these cases, Spring Boot 2.x provides the following base property for configuring custom provider properties: spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.[providerId].

The following listing shows an example:
For these cases, Spring Boot 2.x provides the following base property for configuring custom provider properties: spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.[providerId].

The following listing shows an example:

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          okta:
            client-id: okta-client-id
            client-secret: okta-client-secret
        provider:
          okta: 
            authorization-uri: https://your-subdomain.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/authorize
            token-uri: https://your-subdomain.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/token
            user-info-uri: https://your-subdomain.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: sub
            jwk-set-uri: https://your-subdomain.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/keys
```

The base property (spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.okta) allows for custom configuration of protocol endpoint locations.