# Integrate Spring Security OAuth2 and Spring Social

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, single-sign-on, spring-social, spring-security-oauth2

I'm working with a Spring Boot + Spring Security OAuth2 application that I believe was inspired by examples from Dave Syer. The application is configured to be an OAuth2 authorization server, with a single public client using the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow. A successful token is configured to be a JWT.

The public Angular client sends a POST request to /oauth/token with a basic auth header containing the client id and secret (this was the easiest way to get the client to authenticate, even though the secret is not private). The body of the request contains username, password, and grant type of "password".

In addition to being an authentication server, the application is a RESTful resource server for users, teams, and organizations.

I'm trying to add an additional SSO authentication flow using Spring Social. I've got Spring Social configured to authenticate through external providers via /auth/[provider]; however, following requests no longer have the SecurityContext correctly set. Possibly, Spring Security OAuth server or client is overriding the SecurityContext?

If I can get the SecurityContext correctly set after the Spring Social flow, I've got a new TokenGranter that allows a new grant type of "social" that would check the SecurityContextHolder for the pre authenticated user.

I'm interested in both a solution to my specific problem with the SecurityContext (I believe it's an issue with Spring OAuth + Social integration), or a different approach for authenticating with external providers and getting a valid JWT from our own auth server.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you happen to have any code you can share? What you're describing is a bit of a challenge to set up, so we could possibly find an answer for you faster if there was some ready-to-run code for us to start with instead of building up such an example on our own.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem on a [JHipster](https://jhipster.github.io/)-generated web application. Finally I decided to go with the `SocialAuthenticationFilter` option from Spring Social (via the `SpringSocialConfigurer`). After a successful social login, the server automatically generates and returns the "own" access token via redirection to the client app.

Here's my try:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter implements EnvironmentAware {

    //...

    @Inject
    private AuthorizationServerTokenServices authTokenServices;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        SpringSocialConfigurer socialCfg = new SpringSocialConfigurer();
        socialCfg
            .addObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<SocialAuthenticationFilter>() {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                public SocialAuthenticationFilter postProcess(SocialAuthenticationFilter filter){
                    filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(
                            new SocialAuthenticationSuccessHandler(
                                    authTokenServices,
                                    YOUR_APP_CLIENT_ID
                            )
                        );
                    return filter;
                }
            });

        http
            //... lots of other configuration ...
            .apply(socialCfg);
    }        
}
```

And the `SocialAuthenticationSuccessHandler` class:

```java
public class SocialAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    public static final String REDIRECT_PATH_BASE = "/#/login";
    public static final String FIELD_TOKEN = "access_token";
    public static final String FIELD_EXPIRATION_SECS = "expires_in";

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    private final AuthorizationServerTokenServices authTokenServices;
    private final String localClientId;

    public SocialAuthenticationSuccessHandler(AuthorizationServerTokenServices authTokenServices, String localClientId){
        this.authTokenServices = authTokenServices;
        this.localClientId = localClientId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
                    throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.debug("Social user authenticated: " + authentication.getPrincipal() + ", generating and sending local auth");
        OAuth2AccessToken oauth2Token = authTokenServices.createAccessToken(convertAuthentication(authentication)); //Automatically checks validity
        String redirectUrl = new StringBuilder(REDIRECT_PATH_BASE)
            .append("?").append(FIELD_TOKEN).append("=")
            .append(encode(oauth2Token.getValue()))
            .append("&").append(FIELD_EXPIRATION_SECS).append("=")
            .append(oauth2Token.getExpiresIn())
            .toString();
        log.debug("Sending redirection to " + redirectUrl);
        response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
    }

    private OAuth2Authentication convertAuthentication(Authentication authentication) {
        OAuth2Request request = new OAuth2Request(null, localClientId, null, true, null,
                null, null, null, null);
        return new OAuth2Authentication(request,
                //Other option: new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getPrincipal(), "N/A", authorities)
                new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(authentication.getPrincipal(), "N/A")
                );
    }

    private String encode(String in){
        String res = in;
        try {
            res = UriUtils.encode(in, GeneralConstants.ENCODING_UTF8);
        } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            log.error("ERROR: unsupported encoding: " + GeneralConstants.ENCODING_UTF8, e);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

This way your client app will receive your web app's access token via redirection to `/#/login?access_token=my_access_token&expires_in=seconds_to_expiration`, as long as you set the corresponding `REDIRECT_PATH_BASE` in `SocialAuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: What is `YOUR_APP_CLIENT_ID` exactly? What is the static `GeneralConstants.ENCODING_UTF8` ?

Comment: `public static final String ENCODING_UTF8 = "UTF-8"`.

Comment: I managed to get my app starting after adding beans for `UsersConnectionRepository`, `SocialAuthenticationServiceLocator` and `SocialUserDetailsService`. I also had to add a cast in the `apply` method like this: `.and().apply((SecurityConfigurer<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity>) socialCfg)`. But how do you now use this from HTML?

Comment: Regarding `YOUR_APP_CLIENT_ID`, you can guess, it's the client ID you want to assign to your OAuth service provider.

Comment: I tried adding this `SocialAuthenticationSuccessHandler` but the application never comes in this code (checked with debugger). Are you starting the processing by going to `/auth/facebook` for example ?

Comment: Yep, going to `http://localhost:8080/auth/facebook` redirects to facebook and then back to the defined callback address.

Answer (score 5):

First, I would strongly recommend you to move away from the *password grant* for such a use case.
Public clients (JavaScript, installed applications) cannot keep their client secret confidential, that's why they MUST NOT be assigned one : any visitor inspecting your JavaScript code can discover the secret, and thus implement the same authentication page you have, storing your users passwords in the process.

The *implicit grant* has been created exactly for what you are doing.
Using a redirection-based flow has the advantage of leaving the authentication mechanism up to the authorization server, instead of having each of your applications have a piece of it : that's mostly the definition of *Single Sign On (SSO)*.

With that said, your question is tightly related to this one I just answered : [Own Spring OAuth2 server together with 3rdparty OAuth providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734305/own-spring-oauth2-server-together-with-3rdparty-oauth-providers/33277590#33277590)

To sum up the answer :

> In the end, it's about how your authorization server secures the AuthorizationEndpoint : /oauth/authorize. Since your authorization server works, you already have a configuration class extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter that handles the security for /oauth/authorize with formLogin. That's where you need to integrate social stuff.

You simply cannot use a password grant for what you're trying to achieve, you must have your public client redirect to the authorization server. The authorization server will then redirect to the social login as its security mechanism for the `/oauth/authorize` endpoint.

Comment: I want to participate in this conversation. I'm lost. I am also have separate custom authentication server but don't understand how 'integrate social staff' in my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.  I am thinking about authenticating with social platform and exchange this token for my own JWT in post authenricate stage. Thanks!

Comment: @maret did you manage to find right resource that explains this in detail?

Comment: @zalis I've decided to go with pure Spring OAuth2 with the additional help of some client logic, that obtains the social token and exchange it for my own JWT token with my authentication server. But this solution requires you to have some server side for your client. Don't know if it will help, but here I've answered my own question(sorry for formatting, don't know how to fix that):http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578040/spring-oauth2-support-auth-and-resource-access-with-both-sso-and-custom-auth-se

Comment: Michael, are you recommending to stay away from password grant since the web GUI is hosted on the same server as the server-side? If so, what are the particular reasons you recommend no password grant? That particular flow type works really well with mobile devices, for example, a mobile device sends credentials over HTTPS, retrieves JWT, and then uses the JWT for future communication. Are you thinking use of password grant in this particular case, hosted webapp, provides a false sense of security?

Comment: @KentJohnson the password grant has valid use cases (your own installed applications -- desktop/mobile), it's just that there are better solutions for web applications, namely the implicit grant. Like I said by definition the password grant tells you _how_ to authenticate users (username+password), and forces that logic down into each web application. Redirection based flows decouple _how_ you authenticate (username+password) from the proof of authorization/authentication (token), leaving the first part up to the authorization server. It's also arguably less code in applications.

Comment: @KentJohnson from a security standpoint, it's also less risky to have one application in charge of storing and collecting user credentials, than to have multiple apps sending user cerendials over the network. One last argument, you can use  the implicit grant as a single-sign-on mechanism, meaning that your user only has to connect once even if he navigates accross different web apps, provided that your authorization server has some kind of session.

Comment: And of course, *never* let third parties use the password grant with your users credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I was starting with the good answer of above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33963286/3351474) however with my version of Spring Security (4.2.8.RELEASE) this fails. The reason is that in `org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor#authenticateIfRequired` the `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken` of the answer is not authenticated. Some GrantedAuthorities have to be passed.
In addition sharing the token in an URL parameter is not good, it should always be hidden in an HTTPs payload or header. Instead a HTML template is loaded and the token value is inserted into a `${token}` placeholder field.

Here the revised version:

**NOTE:** The used `UserDetails` here is implementing `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails`

```java
@Component
public class SocialAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Qualifier("tokenServices")
    @Autowired
    private AuthorizationServerTokenServices authTokenServices;

    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        IClient user = ((SocialUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUser();
        // registration is not finished, forward the user, a marker interface 
        // IRegistration is used here, remove this if there no two step approach to 
        // create a user from a social network
        if (user instanceof IRegistration) {
            response.sendRedirect(subscriberRegistrationUrl + "/" + user.getId());
        }
        OAuth2AccessToken token = loginUser(user);
        // load a HTML template from the class path and replace the token placeholder within, the HTML should contain a redirect to the actual page, but must store the token in a safe place, e.g. for preventing CSRF in the `sessionStorage` JavaScript storage.
        String html = IOUtils.toString(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/html/socialLoginRedirect.html"));
        html = html.replace("${token}", token.getValue());
        response.getOutputStream().write(html.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

    private OAuth2Authentication convertAuthentication(Authentication authentication) {
        OAuth2Request request = new OAuth2Request(null, authentication.getName(),
                authentication.getAuthorities(), true, null,
                null, null, null, null);
        // note here the passing of the authentication.getAuthorities()
        return new OAuth2Authentication(request,
                new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(authentication.getPrincipal(), "N/A",  authentication.getAuthorities())
        );
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user.
     */
    public OAuth2AccessToken loginUser(IClient user) {
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails(user);
        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, "N/A", userDetails.getAuthorities());
        securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
        OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication = convertAuthentication(authentication);
        // delete the token because the client id in the DB is calculated as hash of the username and client id (here also also identical to username), this would be identical to the
        // to an existing user. This existing one can come from a user registration or a previous user with the same name.
        // If a new entity with a different ID is used the stored token hash would differ and the the wrong token would be retrieved 
        tokenStore.deleteTokensForUserId(user.getUsername());
        OAuth2AccessToken oAuth2AccessToken = authTokenServices.createAccessToken(oAuth2Authentication);
        // the DB id of the created user is returned as additional data, can be 
        // removed if not needed
        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) oAuth2AccessToken).setAdditionalInformation(new HashMap<>());
        oAuth2AccessToken.getAdditionalInformation().put("userId", user.getId());
        return oAuth2AccessToken;
    }

}
```

Example `socialLoginRedirect.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example App</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=/index.html#/home"/>
</head>
<script>
     window.sessionStorage.setItem('access_token', '${token}');
</script>
<body>
<p>Please follow <a href="/index.html#/home">this link</a>.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The configuration wiring in a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvc
@Import(WebServiceConfig.class)
public class AuthenticationConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${registrationUrl}")
    private String registrationUrl;

    @Autowired
    private SocialAuthenticationSuccessHandler socialAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Value("${loginUrl}")
    private String loginUrl;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        List<String> permitAllUrls = new ArrayList<>();
        // permit social log in
        permitAllUrls.add("/auth/**");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(permitAllUrls.toArray(new String[0])).permitAll();

        SpringSocialConfigurer springSocialConfigurer = new SpringSocialConfigurer();
        springSocialConfigurer.signupUrl(registrationUrl);
        springSocialConfigurer.postFailureUrl(loginUrl);
        springSocialConfigurer
                .addObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<SocialAuthenticationFilter>() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    public SocialAuthenticationFilter postProcess(SocialAuthenticationFilter filter){
                        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(socialAuthenticationSuccessHandler);
                        return filter;
                    }
                });
        http.apply(springSocialConfigurer);

        http.logout().disable().csrf().disable();

        http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented spring oauth2 to secure my rest services and additionally add social login and implicit signup for first time login . for user user you can generate the token using username and password only problem with generate the token for social user . for that you have to implement the Filter that will intercept your /oauth/token request before processing . here if you want to generate the the token for social user pass the username and facebook token , here you can use facebook token as password and generate the token for facebook user also . if facebook token updated then you have to write a db trigger also to update you token in user table .... may be it will help you