# Spring Boot OAuth2 manually create new JWT token

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-social, spring-oauth2

At my Spring Boot application I have configured Spring OAuth2 server with JWT tokens.

Also I have added Spring Social configuration in order to be able authenticate users via various Social Networks like Twitter, Facebook and so on.

This is my `SpringSocial` config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig extends SocialConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository) {
        return new ProviderSignInController(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository, new SimpleSignInAdapter(authTokenServices, "client_id", userService));
    }

...

}
```

Also, based on the folksinging answer [Integrate Spring Security OAuth2 and Spring Social](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32313821/integrate-spring-security-oauth2-and-spring-social) I have implemented `SimpleSignInAdapter` in order to handle successful authentication with 3rdparty Social Networks:

```
public class SimpleSignInAdapter implements SignInAdapter {

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleSignInAdapter.class);

    public static final String REDIRECT_PATH_BASE = "/#/login";
    public static final String FIELD_TOKEN = "access_token";
    public static final String FIELD_EXPIRATION_SECS = "expires_in";

    private final AuthorizationServerTokenServices authTokenServices;
    private final String localClientId;
    private final UserService userService;

    public SimpleSignInAdapter(AuthorizationServerTokenServices authTokenServices, String localClientId, UserService userService){
        this.authTokenServices = authTokenServices;
        this.localClientId = localClientId;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public String signIn(String userId, Connection<?> connection, NativeWebRequest request) {

        UserDetails userDetails = loadUserById(Long.parseLong(userId));

        OAuth2AccessToken oauth2Token = authTokenServices.createAccessToken(convertAuthentication(userDetails)); 
        String redirectUrl = new StringBuilder(REDIRECT_PATH_BASE)
            .append("?").append(FIELD_TOKEN).append("=")
            .append(encode(oauth2Token.getValue()))
            .append("&").append(FIELD_EXPIRATION_SECS).append("=")
            .append(oauth2Token.getExpiresIn())
            .toString();    

        return redirectUrl;
    }

    private OAuth2Authentication convertAuthentication(UserDetails userDetails) {
        OAuth2Request request = new OAuth2Request(null, localClientId, null, true, null, null, null, null, null);
        return new OAuth2Authentication(request, new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, "N/A", userDetails.getAuthorities()));
    }

    private String encode(String in) {
        String res = in;
        try {
            res = UriUtils.encode(in, "UTF-8");
        } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            logger.error("ERROR: unsupported encoding: " + "UTF-8", e);
        }
        return res;
    }

    public UserDetails loadUserById(Long id) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.findUserById(id);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + id + " not found.");
        }

        Set<Permission> permissions = userService.getUserPermissions(user);
        return new DBUserDetails(user, permissions);
    }

}
```

Everything works fine except one thing - the following line of code produces plain OAuth2 access token:

```
OAuth2AccessToken oauth2Token = authTokenServices.createAccessToken(convertAuthentication(userDetails));
```

but I need to create JWT token instead.

How to create or convert this token to JWT based ? I suppose I can use `JwtAccessTokenConverter` class for this purpose but don't know how at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging I have found a solution:

```
private final TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer;

...
OAuth2Authentication authentication = convertAuthentication(userDetails);
OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = authTokenServices.createAccessToken(authentication); 
accessToken = tokenEnhancer.enhance(accessToken, authentication);
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, after i wanted my own Custom JWT token.

```
DefaultTokenServices service = new DefaultTokenServices(); 
    service.setTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter);
    service.setTokenEnhancer(jwtAccessTokenConverter);
    OAuth2AccessToken token = service.createAccessToken(authentication);
```

Autowire the jwtAccessTokenConverter

```
@Autowired
private JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter;
```